# How to refer outer closure parameter from subclosure in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Consider the following list

```
def days = [ 'monday', 'tuesday']
```

and the `each` closure with another (sub)closure inside

```
days.each { it ->
    println "it = $it (outer closure)"    // prints day

    def cloz = {
        println "it = $it (subclosure)"   // prints null, how to print day?
    }
    cloz()
}
```

`it` closure is unreachable from `cloz` subclosure. How to refer outer closure parameter from subclosure?

Comment: Sensible variable naming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could get the behavior you want.  The problem is that the implicit `it` variable in your inner closure is stepping on the explicit `it` parameter from your outer closure.

You could do something like this:

```
def days = [ 'monday', 'tuesday']

days.each { outer ->
    println "it = $outer (outer closure)"    // prints day

    def cloz = { inner ->
        println "it = $outer (subclosure)"   // prints day
    }
    cloz()
}
```

Or this:

```
def days = [ 'monday', 'tuesday']

days.each { day ->
    println "it = $day (outer closure)"    // prints day

    def cloz = { 
        println "it = $day (subclosure)"   // prints day
    }
    cloz()
}
```

Etc...

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok. Cool. Thanks. And is there any way how to refer outer closure using "super" keyword or something similar? For the case as above when outer close param name is hidden by inner close param name.

Comment: @LiborJelinek `super` won't do it because `super` will refer to the parent class of whatever class your closures are defined in.  It may be that `owner` will get you what you want, but wanting to refer to the containing closure is a little bit of a peculiar thing to want to do.  Can you clarify why it is that you want to do that?

Comment: Owner refers to a class, not to closure parameter. It was just "an academic" question. Your answer is more than enough for me and thank you Jeff!

Comment: @LiborJelinek "Owner refers to a class" - `owner` does not refer to a class.  `owner` refers to the the object that created the closure.  You asked "is there any way how to refer outer closure" and from the inner closure, `owner` is the closest thing to that but there isn't really any good reason to want to do that.